# How to change SMTP details in Typo3 directly from directory?

Tags: smtp, typo3

Quick Question!

I need to change the SMTP details in a Typo3 site.  Normally, you can do this by going to the install tool > all configuration.
That however is password protested and I don't know it!  (The guy who does know it is not available)

Can I change these details directly from a file in the FTP server?  If so, which file? I can't find it, and any documentation I've checked out doesn't help!

Ty!

Answer (score 2):

the configuration from the install tool is stored in `typo3conf/localconf.php` (up until version 4.7) or in `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` (since version 6.0).

The configuration regarding SMTP has to be put into $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['MAIL']:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['MAIL'] = array(
    'transport' => 'smtp',
    'transport_smtp_server' => 'smtp.yourdomain.org',
    'transport_smtp_encrypt' => 'ssl', /* Usually available: ssl, sslv2, sslv3, tls. Check stream_get_transports(). */
    'transport_smtp_username' => 'username',
    'transport_smtp_username => 'password',
);
```

The formatting of the generated file is different in the two versions, but the array structure is the same. Be aware that changes to the localconf.php/LocalConfiguration.php might be overwritten by the install tool.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @jost answer, you may **temporary** set in your localconf:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['installToolPassword'] = 'bacb98acf97e0b6112b1d1b650b84971';
```

which corresponds to well-known 'joh316' and get access to Install Tool.

After you done with changes there, don't forget to restore old Install Tool password hash!

Answer (score 0):

IN Your localconf.php add

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['MAIL']['transport'] = 'smtp';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['MAIL']['transport_smtp_server'] = 'smtp.gmail.com:465';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['MAIL']['transport_smtp_port'] = '465';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['MAIL']['transport_smtp_encrypt'] ='ssl'; # requires openssl in PHP
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['MAIL']['transport_smtp_username'] = '*****@gmail.com';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['MAIL']['transport_smtp_password'] = '*****';
```

then in your php file use

```
$mailContent = $mailcontent;
$mailContent = ($mailContent);
// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mail = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_mail_Message');

 $mail->setFrom(array('sender email' => 'sender name'));

//$mail->setBcc(array($this->bcc => $this->bcc));
$mail->setSubject($subject);
$mail->setBody($mailContent,'text/html');
$mail->setTo(array('reciever email' => 'name'));    
$mail->send();
```